# Hippos, hippos everywhere but not a drop to drink

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Where can you find:

- a hippo showering with no water?
- a rabid hippo with no one to bite?
- a sleeping hippo with no bed to lay on?
- a hippo smelling the flowers where none can be found?

(one answer)

**Hint #1**

> I chose the word "hippo" very specifically as opposed to "hippopotamus"

**Hint #2**

> She's not the hippo you think she is. Opa!

**Hint #3**

> At night she is a scary 'hippo'

Comment: this is my first attempt at a riddle so any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps at a rot13(uvccb onol fubjre)?

Comment: heh, not quite :)

Comment: Does it have anything to do with Greek mythology?

Comment: Not that I'm specifically aware of

Comment: I just found one in a kid's drawing book!

Comment: This seems ambiguous: any story involving hippos and some random idiomatic phrase containing "shower" would seem correct (unless of course there is some other information here that I'm missing). Is there other information I am not considering?

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, @AustinWeaver. I wanted to make sure the tag pushed people in a certain direction because it's a few layers deep.

Comment: Re Hint 2: [relevant?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opa!_(Greek_expression))

Comment: @Randal'Thor "yes" I sure hope I'm not leading people on the wrong path...

Comment: I think "hippo" is leading people astray...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some of the info from other responses, my closest guess is...

> The moon.

Because...

> Opa referring to the Greeks, implying "hippo" potentially as "horse." Then the last hint being "scary at night", I was also thinking "nightmare." So I went with mare. Where else do you find mare? On the moon, with "mare" meaning "sea" or "ocean." There is a Mare Imbrium (Sea of Showers - shower without water), Mare Tranquillatus (Sea of Tranquility - sleeping without a bed), Mare Spumans (Foaming Sea - rabid) and then Mare Nectaris (Sea of Nectar - smell of flower where none can be found).

I'm fairly confident on this one!

Comment: Amazing! I was starting to get worried there that I really messed this up. :)

Comment: That was a fantastic one, loved the hints.

Comment: It was really hard to come up with hints that didnt' outright convert hippo to horse or to mare...

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert in this, but could this be any of

> hippo-campus, hippo-talamys or hippo-phys? 
>  I remember that hypocampus is responsible for smells, so might it be...?

Also

> Showering without water might be a sign of hippo-thermia.

Comment: Very clever. Unfortunately not quite. That sounds like an interesting riddle in it's own right.

Answer (score 3):

I won't be able to solve this, but combining the hints:

> Since "Opa!" is a Greek expression, and 'Hippo' was used specifically, maybe we should be looking at horses (hippo- prefix comes from the Greek word for horse)?

Edit:

Though I can't explain it fully, your new clue (and the third example) is making me think:

> It's a Nightmare (or just a dream?)

Comment: You're on the right track. :)

Comment: Keep going. There are more clues in the previous hints to help narrow it down. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, because it's [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), I'm going to say:

> [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1941165052)

This is because:

> The cover of the book I linked to, "It's Raining Hippos", has a girl being showered with hippos. Hippos are literally falling onto her and she for some reason looks ecstatic. It's a hippo showering! And hippos ≠ water. You cannot drink hippos.

Comment: Nice. That's an amazing coincidence.